# AdaBoost with gridsearch can't use permutation_test_score

Tags: python, scikit-learn, adaboost

I'm trying to evaluate the performance of my AdaBoosted decision tree against random chance.

```
dcf = AdaBoostClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2,  
max_features="auto", min_samples_split=3, 
min_samples_leaf=14), 
algorithm="SAMME",random_state=123)
clf = GridSearchCV(dcf, param_grid, scoring='accuracy', cv=5)

clf.fit(train_dat, train_labels)
```

However, when I want to add a permutation test:

```
score, permutation_scores, pvalue = permutation_test_score(
clf.best_estimator_, test_dat,test_labels, scoring="accuracy", cv=5, n_permutations=600, n_jobs=1)
```

my error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "adaboost-test.py", line 99, in <module>
    clf.best_estimator_, test_dat,test_labels, scoring="accuracy", cv=5, n_permutations=600, n_jobs=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 1092, in permutation_test_score
    score = _permutation_test_score(clone(estimator), X, y, groups, cv, scorer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 1109, in _permutation_test_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py", line 427, in fit
    return super().fit(X, y, sample_weight)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py", line 150, in fit
    random_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py", line 490, in _boost
    random_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py", line 579, in _boost_discrete
    raise ValueError('BaseClassifier in AdaBoostClassifier '
ValueError: BaseClassifier in AdaBoostClassifier ensemble is worse than random, ensemble can not be fit.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says it all.

```
ValueError: BaseClassifier in AdaBoostClassifier ensemble is worse than random, ensemble can not be fit.
```

This error comes from `AdaBoostClassifier()`, not your permutation test. Your base learner is too weak for the certain permutation of your data to give you any meaningful result. Check your data and Decision Tree model.

Comment: But I'm trying to use the boosted tree as the input not the Base Classifier. How then do I evaluate the boosted tree using random permutation? Also I'm not sure what "too weak" means.

Comment: For your ensemble method `AdaBoostClassifier()` to be effective, it should do better than random guess. In the case of classification, it should do better than 50% of the time. Your base learner, `DecisionTreeClassifier()` does not for a certain permutation of your train data. If your base learner is too weak, there is no point in "boosting", so no point in permutation test. This explains quite well: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82049/what-is-meant-by-weak-learner